# Rewriting URL to sub domain

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I have a joomla installed site. I have many links to mysite.com/user/... I want to add a rule in .htaccess to rewrite mysite.com/user/everything and mysite.com/user/everything/.../everything and so on, to user.mysite.com/everything and so on. I've used the following in the top of joomla's .htaccess just after RewriteEngine On. But it does not work.

`RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ user.zagrosdata.com/$1 [L]`
]

Comment: You have my blessing to try it

Comment: Sorry for incomplete post! The code does not work.

Comment: This isn't rewriting, this is redirecting.

Comment: Sorry for unclear question.I wrote in hurry! In many pages of joomla I hav links to mysite.com/user/... and I don't want to change all links instead just rewrite them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an *external* redirect, you either prepend http(s)://, use the `R=301/R=302` flag, or more likely / clean: both:

```
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ http://user.zagrosdata.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: When browse to zagrosdata.com url is rewritten as zagrosdata.com/fa. However there is no folder called fa. Links to zagrosdata.com/... are within page with url http://zagrosdata.com/fa/web-hosting/persional-linux-host.html

Comment: .. which means... something is redirecting your subdomain back... to it's original domain sans 'user'... so, you have conflicting rules somewhere. Might want to post those.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^http://zagrosdata.com/user/(.*)$ http://user.zagrosdata.com/$1 [L,R=301]` is not going to work.. only the PATH is available in `RewriteRule`'s

Comment: BTW: is your Joomla (brrr...) install even set up to serve & recognize that subdomain?

Comment: this sub domain is not part of joomla. It contains clients portal which is WHMCS.

Comment: Well instead of those subdomain rules you have in there now, what does `RewriteRule ^/?user/(.*)$ http://user.zagrosdata.com/$1 [L,R=301] ` actually do?